# Don't we need the axiom of choice to choose from a non-empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I recently read a proof that had the following in it: "since $A$ is non-empty, we can find an element $x$ in $A$." This proof did not mention the axiom of choice, but it seems to me that it would be required to make the proof formal. Would I not require a choice function to allow me to find/pick some element $x$ from $A$ after noting that A is non-empty? Thanks

Comment: No, you don’t need AC: you can always pick a single element from a non-empty set.

Comment: Could you please explain why. I understand that there obviously exists an element in A, but why do I not need the axiom of choice to choose such an element?

Comment: It follows from [one of the rules of first-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation). Informally, that rule says that from $\exists x~\varphi(x)$ one may infer $\varphi(c)$, where $c$ is a new name created specifically for the purpose of naming something that has the property $\varphi$.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for this!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Mmmm, a bit misleading, methinks. Take an ND system. Given $\exists x\varphi(x)$, you make the (temporary) new assumption $\varphi(c)$, deduce something $\psi$ that doesn't depend on $c$, and discharge the assumption and conclude $\psi$ by $\exists$-elimination. But at no point do you *infer* something like $\varphi(c)$.

Comment: Of course, one could add a [choice operator](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/choice+operator) to the logical system, in which case one really can infer $\varphi (c)$ from $\exists x . \varphi (x)$, where $c = \tau_x \varphi (x)$...

Answer (score 10):

The axiom of choice is needed when you need to make *infinitely* many arbitrary choices at once.

Recall that a set $A$ is not empty if and only if $\exists x. x\in A$, so assuming that $A$ is not empty we can provably pick such $x$.

Comment: You might want to qualify that first sentence: it’s when you make infinitely many *arbitrary* choices. It’s the old socks versus shoes business: given infinitely many pairs of shoes, you don’t need the axiom of choice to form the set of left shoes.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, although it was boots in the original version methinks.

Comment: You’re probably right, since as I recall the original was British.

Comment: It was probably [Bertrand Russell](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/ccc/choice.html) as the originator of shoes/socks analogy?

Comment: @Mahmud: Yes, that was Russell.